# kivyのidsをpython側で指定する方法

Tags: python, kivy

kivyでpython からidを指定した状態で追加しようとしました。

```
self.tabble.add_widget(Button(ids="mass"+str(_),text='mass'+str(_)))
```

しかし以下のエラーが出ます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 262, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1048, in kivy.properties.DictProperty.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 952, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__init__
 ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

https://pyky.github.io/kivy-doc-ja/api-kivy.uix.widget.html やエラー内容から、本来入力すべきものは辞書であると推察しましたが,具体的に何を入れればいいかわかりません。

**わからない事1**

辞書は"id":dataであり最低でも二つあります。どちらにidの名前を入れ,逆にもう一つは何なのかが知りたいです。

**わからない事2**

kvからではid: ○○と入力するため単なるテキスト型だとおもっていました。なぜ辞書型なのでしょうか。もしかして一つのウィジットに複数のidをつけれるのでしょうか？

Comment: これらの記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[How to set id for widgets in kivy from python code file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69317381/9014308), [Kivy ids in python code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46540977/9014308), [Difference between "name" and "id" attributes in Kivy, and when should I use each](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63985768/9014308), [Kivy returning AttributeError: object has no attribute 'name' when it clearly has it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60995183/9014308), [Python : How to set id of button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50099151/9014308)

Comment: 参考までに、この記事にpythonとkivyを古い版数にダウングレードしたら似たようなことが出来たらしいという質問者によるコメントが付いていますね。[Pass button id using python main file: kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67512612/9014308)